# Thank you for (spending / putting / taking) your time

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, difference, sentence-structure

I wonder if you could let me know which one of the listed sentences below is more appropriate for thanking someone when the spend some time to help you?

Is there any uncommon or unidiomatic sentence between them that doesn't sound natural to you? If yes, please that explain me.

> - Thank you for **spending your time** helping / to help me me. 
>    - Thank you for **putting your time** helping / to help me. 
>    - Thank you for **taking your time** helping / to help me.

To me, all the sentences above mean the same, but I need to know what do you think about their connotations?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Thank you for spending your time helping / to help me.

This is fine. Our time is ours to spend, so "spending *your* time" makes perfect sense.

> Thank you for taking your time helping / to help me.

This is not quite right. We wouldn't say "taking *your* time", it should be:

> Thank you for taking **the** time to help me

I guess you don't take something that is already yours. This expression "taking time" means buying out time to do something.

You could take "Putting your time" and use it like so;

> Thank you for putting your time *toward* helping me / helping me out

Since you are putting your time somewhere, a directional word like "toward" completes the phrase.

Comment: Thank you very much @Astralbee, just I need to make sure if "to put time is a tottaly unidiomatic verb or not; so please let me know whether I can say: "If you're going to succeed, you have to put more time/take more time/spend more time** for your studies"? According to what you mentioned, in this sentence, "put" version won't work at all; the version with "take" also doesn't work and the only possible verb would be "spend". Do you agree?

Comment: This pretty much gets the gist of it. But your missing a tiny bit of information. see "Putting the time to help" can be used in a different way, as you can use it as "Thanks you for Putting your time toward helping me out / helping me"

Comment: @A-friend Taylor Spark's comment is correct and has been incorporated into my answer now - you can use "putting" but just not in the way you did, see my updated answer.

Comment: Well @Astralbee, just to come to a conclusion, do you ahree that I can say: "spend **the / your** time, while I just can use "take **the** time"?

Answer (score 3):

In case you would like a more formal phrase, for instance used in a business context, a good alternative would be [(GrammarHow)](https://grammarhow.com/better-ways-to-say-thank-you-for-taking-the-time/):

> Thank you for dedicating your time to our project

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/135499)

Comment: @Joachim This answer addresses the OP's question about ways to thank someone, and could be useful to someone with this same question in the future.