# (Taking / putting in) the time + infinitive or gerund verb

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-choice

I am wondering which following sentences does not sound idiomatic? (To me they all mean the same thing. If there is any nuance, then please let me know.)

> **1.a.** Thank you for **taking** the time "**helping** me". 
>   **1.b.** Thank you for **taking** the time "**to help** me". 
>   **2.a.** Thank you for **putting in** the time "**helping** me." 
>   **2.b.** Thank you for **putting in** the time "**to help** me."

P.S. [My old thread](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/209823/thank-you-for-spending-putting-taking-your-time) is unable to answer this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiom ["take the time"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+the+time) is normally followed by the to-infinitive whereas ["put in (some time)](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+in+time+on)"--by the preposition "on".

So, "Thank you for taking the time to help me" sounds quite idiomatic.

Comment: Please kindly let me know what is wrong with the other options @Victor B.

Comment: @A-friend - They're just not idiomatic, even if they will be understood. Once you're using an idiom, use it as it is set as an unchangeable expression)